# UNIX Timestamp or something else?

Tags: unix-timestamp

I have a field containing what should be a UNIX time stamp. As an example one value is `1408675380`

Now when I do various online conversions, it shows the right day (22nd August) but shows the incorrect time. It should be around 21:00 or so but instead shows `02:43:00 GMT`

Likewise, `1408676520` shows the correct day (22nd August) but instead of showing a time of around 22:00/23:00 it shows `03:02:00 GMT`

I have no control over the data at all - just wondering if there's something obvious I'm missing?

`1408849260` - Sunday, August 24th 2014, 03:01:00 (GMT) - Correct day, around 18 hours too early
`1408850640` - Sunday, August 24th 2014, 03:24:00 (GMT) - Correct day, around 18 hours too early

Thanks,

JJ

Comment: Obvious question to ask - what timezone are you/your software in? Also, could you give a few examples of "number `xxxx` corresponds to `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm` in the software". I think that data is in your question but you've presented it in a very piecemeal fashion

Comment: It's a JSON file if that makes any difference and the time difference is constantly around 18 hours

Comment: It's summer time, so this looks most likely to be a timestamp being interpreted in relation to US Mountain Time (Mountain Daylight Savings Time). There's no GMT+18 timezone (it goes to +14 for Kiribati). If you have a linux box you can do `date --date=@1408675380` where you're interpreting the timezone. That will provide time based on the timezone you're using for interpreting the UNIX timestamp (which is UTC)

Comment: Just been told that the times are incorrect and will be sorted out ASAP. Got to love senior managers.

Answer (score 0):

Is your data in some other timezone than GMT ? something like GMT-5 (america west cost maybe ?)

Comment: The time difference is around 18 hours